How to get screenshot of full screen window including secondary monitor in MAUI (iOS and Windows)
How to get screenshot of full screen window including secondary monitor in MAUI (iOS and Windows).
Already MAUI has Screenshot.
Screenshot.Default.CaptureAsync();

But it just capture the app only. I need full screen image.

Do you mean you want to screenshot the entire device screen?

Yes @JianweiSun-MSFT

If so, use the screenshot function that comes with the device?

The code below makes it possible to take a screenshot of the active screen on Windows. It only supports the active screen and is a Windows-only solution so it doesn't fully answer the OP's question, however, it might help people. This solution is based on this post.
1.
Create a new project (named 'test' in this example)
2.
Install the System.Drawing.Common NuGet package.
3.
Create this class under Platforms\Windows:


using System.Drawing;

namespace test.Platforms.Windows
{
    public class ScreenshotHelper
    {
        public static Rectangle GetPrimaryScreenBounds()
        {
            var displayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
            int width = (int)displayInfo.Width;
            int height = (int)displayInfo.Height;

            return new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        }

        private static Bitmap CopyFromScreen(Rectangle bounds)
        {
            try
            {
                var image = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
                using var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image);
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(System.Drawing.Point.Empty, System.Drawing.Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                return image;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { 
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static System.Drawing.Image Take()
        {
            var bounds = GetPrimaryScreenBounds();
            return CopyFromScreen(bounds);
        }

        public static byte[] TakeAsByteArray()
        {
            var bounds = GetPrimaryScreenBounds();
            using var image = CopyFromScreen(bounds);
            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        public static void TakeAndSave(string path)
        {
            var bounds = GetPrimaryScreenBounds();
            using var image = CopyFromScreen(bounds);
            image.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}



4.
Create a button on your View:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="test.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Button
                Text="Capture screenshot" 
                Clicked="OnCaptureButtonClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>



5.
Modify your code-behind:


using test.Platforms.Windows;


namespace test
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private async void OnCaptureButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            string fileName = $"Screenshot_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.png";
            string filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName);
            ScreenshotHelper.TakeAndSave(filePath);
            await DisplayAlert("Screenshot Saved", $"Saved to {filePath}", "OK");

        }

    }

}



